# powershell script not interpreting file path correctly

Tags: powershell

I have an issue where a path to a file is generated by an application.  So the path looks like this….
Unfortunately, this output is generated from an application…so I cannot manipulate the output.
[image]

Now…when I run my powershell script to copy the file …I get the following errors
[image]

It seems that the problem is that my powershell script is not getting the path correctly….

```
$folders = Get-Content -Path '\\TFA-APP-01\CUI\WS\FOUNDFILES\results.txt'
$dest = '\\TFA-APP-01\CUI\WS\FOUNDFILES\found\'
$excludes = "WS","FOUNDFILES"



    foreach ($folder in $folders) {
#           Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | Where-Object{$_.Name -notin $excludes} | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | Where-Object{$_.Name -notin $excludes} | Where-Object{$_.FullName -like 'Desktop'} | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | Where-Object{$_.Name -notin $excludes} | Where-Object{$_.FullName -like 'Documents'} | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | Where-Object{$_.Name -notin $excludes} | Where-Object{$_.FullName -like 'Downloads'} | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | Where-Object{$_.Name -notin $excludes} | Where-Object{$_.FullName -like 'Outlook'} | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | Where-Object{$_.Name -notin $excludes} | Where-Object{$_.FullName -like 'INetCache'} | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | Where-Object{$_.Name -notin $excludes} | Where-Object{$_.FullName -like 'Attachments'} | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

}
```

How can I either parse the results.txt file and extract just the file paths to another text file?
Or how can I modify my CopyResults.ps1 script to interpret the file path correctly?

Comment: Notepad supports copying text; you don't need to (and should not) take screenshots of it.  Your input file lines contain more information than just the file path and name, but you're not doing anything to extract just the path.

Comment: To add additional information to Lance's comment: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as ([properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that Get-Content converts every line of a file into an element of an array, and you don't want to look at every line. You want to look at a specific part of a specific line that repeats in a specific pattern.

Because of all of these constants, we can make a pretty simple script to get the information you want.

```
$paths = Get-Content C:\temp\paths.txt

for ($i = 1; $i -lt $paths.Length; $i += 3) {
    $path = "$($paths[$i].Split('.txt')[0]).txt"

    $path # \\SERVER\PATH\FILE.TXT
}
```

Your file has a pattern of [empty line, path line, company line]. If we think about the .txt file as an array with many subarrays of that pattern, we can see that we want to get the 1st index (`$i = 1`) for every set of 3 (`$i += 3`) in the file.

Since I split by .txt, I have to [string interpolate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions?view=powershell-7.2) the .txt extension back on.

Edit:

Here's the script modified for your issues

```
$paths = Get-Content C:\temp\paths.txt

for ($i = 1; $i -lt $paths.Length; $i += 3) {
    $pathSplit = $paths[$i].Split('.')
    $extension = $pathSplit[1].split(' ')[0]
    $path = "${$pathSplit[0]).$extension"

    $path # \\SERVER\PATH\FILE.TXT
}
```

`$pathSplit` is split at the extension into 2 parts. One is the majority of the path and the other is the rest of the line.

`$extension` looks at the 1st index and splits by the space in order to isolate the file extension.

Finally, `$path` combines `$pathSplit[0]` and `$extension` to give you the full file path.

Comment: Ok....when I change the Get-Content path to my 'results.txt' file and change the variable $path to '$folders' (so it will run through the filtering)....what happens is it went through the 'results.txt' file and appended each path     \\TRIFABPC-138\C$\Windows\WinS.txt

\\TRIFABPC-138\C$\Windows\WinS.txt
.txt
\\TRIFABPC-138\C$\Windows\WinS.txt
.txt
22646 "DODB"="ãŸ¬" .txt
Get-ChildItem : Illegal characters in path.
At D:\Data Shares\CUI\WS\CopyResults2.ps1:14 char:4
+             Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | Where-Object{$_.Name -notin ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: how do I add your script within my script so it doesn't just change every path to \\server\path\\*.txt   within results.txt ?

Comment: Also note....all the files in results.txt are not just text files (I am filtering for excel, word, powerpoint, etc. etc.) so I would want to do "*.*" (or equivalent) instead of just *.txt  (I tried changing from *.txt to "*.*" and this just changed the paths in results.txt to \\server\\path\(cut off).*

Comment: Check my edits :). Sorry for the late response

Comment: As for the error, I'm not so sure that had anything to do with my code. It sounds like you modified the data it output and that is where something went wrong

Comment: you're probably right....

Comment: thank you for your edits  (I really am just winging it here)